# make 2 select statements from 2 tables and then join the result with third table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database with three tables:

Table 1

```
CREATE TABLE "A" ( "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL 
                  ,"cat_id" INTEGER NOT NULL
                  ,"date" DATETIME NOT NULL
                  ,"amount" VARCHAR NOT NULL  DEFAULT (0.0)
                  ,"notes" VARCHAR)
```

Table 2:

```
CREATE TABLE "B" ( "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL
                  ,"cat_id" INTEGER NOT NULL
                  ,"date" DATETIME NOT NULL
                  ,"amount" VARCHAR NOT NULL  DEFAULT (0.0)
                  ,"notes" VARCHAR)
```

Table 3:

```
CREATE TABLE "c" ( "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL
                  ,"parent_id" INTEGER NOT NULL  DEFAULT (0)
                  ,"name" VARCHAR NOT NULL
                  ,"position" INTEGER NOT NULL
                  ,"importance" INTEGER NOT NULL  DEFAULT (0)
                  ,"transaction_type" VARCHAR NOT NULL  DEFAULT expenses
                  ,"icon" VARCHAR NOT NULL  DEFAULT default
                  ,"budget" INTEGER NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0
                  ,"status" INTEGER NOT NULL  DEFAULT 1)
```

I use this statement to select from the tables `A` and `B`:

```
SELECT * FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM B 
ORDER BY date
```

I want to join the result of this select statement with  the third table `C` with:

```
RIGHT JOIN C on A.cat_id = C.id
RIGHT JOIN C on B.cat_id = C.id
```

How can i do this?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it just by combining the elements of the SQL language:

```
select ab.*, c.*
from ((SELECT *
       FROM A
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT *
       FROM B
      )
     ) ab right join
     C
     on ab.cat_id = c.id
ORDER BY date
```

This makes the union all a subquery and then does the join from there.

Comment: thanks for ur replay , my problem solved :) , but without the inner brackets so it worked with me like that : select ab.*, c.*
from (SELECT *
       FROM A
       UNION ALL
      SELECT *
       FROM B
      
     ) ab right join
     C
     on ab.cat_id = c.id
ORDER BY date

Answer (score 0):

Also you can join then union tables) Like distributive property in math:

```
select *
from (
      (SELECT * FROM A right join C
        on ab.cat_id = c.id) 
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT * FROM B right join C
        on ab.cat_id = c.id)
     ) ab 
ORDER BY date
```

Hovewer, this is not the best way, due to double join.